# Nginx behind LB : http_x_forwarded_for not used for limit_req_zone

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

I am trying to set a rate limit based on the client IP and am facing an issue. I am behind a load balancer whose ip is 10.0.0.1. the trafic is

```
clients ---> (internet) ---> LB ---> Nginx ---> MyApp
```

I am using the official nginx docker image version 1.19.6

I used the following config, based on the official nginx doc https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/

```
limit_req_dry_run on;

geo $limit {
    default 1;
    192.168.0.0/24 0;
}

map $limit $limit_key {
    0 "";
    1 $http_x_forwarded_for;
}

limit_req_zone $limit_key zone=limit_all:10m rate=1r/s;
```

I am also using the below log format :

```
log_format logFormat '$http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local] '
'"$request" $status $request_length $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
'rt=$request_time msec=$msec cid=$cid';
```

However the configuration does not work : It seems Nginx ignore the http_x_forwarded_for and use the IP of the load balancer as client ip. I have the following dry run log (I anonymised some info):

```
021/05/17 16:47:28 [error] 22#22: *164 limiting requests, dry run, excess: 0.300 by zone "limit_all", client: 10.0.0.1, server: XXXX, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "XXXX", referrer: "my/route"
```

what is strange is that the log however shows the correct source IP of the client (first parameter of log format is '$http_x_forwarded_for) :

```
176.185.151.XXX- - [17/May/2021:16:47:28 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1152 138173 "https://my/route/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36" rt=0.005 msec=1621262848.720 cid=
```

how come the http_x_forwarded_for has the correct value in the nginx log but not in the rate limit configuration ? Could you point out what I am missing here ? thanks a lot !

Comment: How did you fix this? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: I was unable to fix it so I used a solution mentioned on other post : 

```geo $limit {
  default 1;
  192.168.11.0/24 0;
}
map $limit $limit_key {
  0 "";
  1 $binary_remote_addr;
}
set_real_ip_from  XXXX/16;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
limit_req_dry_run on;
limit_req_zone $http_x_forwarded_for zone=limit_static:10m rate=1r/s;

``` 

where  XXXX/16 is the IP range used by the LB